# Can IRB approval be reversed?

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, irb

If you get the written [IRB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_review_board) approval of the school/site for research
and you conduct the research with all participants' written agreement, can the school revoke agreement to research after you are done with the research?

An IRB was signed. Research for dissertation. can the research site revoke the agreement after the research was conducted?

Research was approved through signed IRBs.
Research was completed and results were done.
How can a school revoke approval if the research was completed?

In essence, I am asking if IRB can withdraw approval from all schools involved after the fact.

Comment: Can you add more details, such as your academic rank, what the agreement was, etc?

Comment: Has this happened or is it just a worry? Do you mean an ethical review (IRB) such as is required in the US and elsewhere was signed off on?

Comment: What do your documents signed with the site say? It definitely doesn't matter if the research is for your dissertation or something else so that seems irrelevant. Why do you think they'd want to withdraw participation?

Comment: Please add whether this has happened already or whether it is just a worry. If it has happened, were you given a reason? The answer to your question could be yes or no depending on the details.

Comment: @Mary - this is a very interesting question. Please [edit] your post to add the details requested above.

Comment: I voted to reopen. The question as asked is clear and can be answered without additional details, even if it would be interesting to read them.

Comment: Ugh. I don't think this question should have been reopened until clarified and I don't think the edits understand the question. I do not think OP is asking about IRB approval being withdrawn. They have a study site, for example a school, that agreed to participate in research. This is a consent process a lot like the consent for an individual. It is not an IRB approval, IRB approval would be with OP's institution. The "research site" is distinct from OP's academic institution. The new question is a good question **but it is not OP's question** unless they phrased the original wrong.

Comment: @BryanKrause -- I agree, but I think for every single path you can run down, the answer is a clear "yes, IRB approval can be revoked"

Comment: @ScottSeidman This wouldn't be the IRB approval, though, it would be more like an individual revoking consent. I know that's standard for continuing in a study but I don't believe it's standard to allow patients to revoke consent for already collected data.

Comment: @BryanKrause This has all gotten very complicated in light of the 2018/2019 changes to the "Common Rule", recognizing that consent also has to do with what happens to tissue samples, which can be stored, or even promulgated, for decades.  GDPR (though this isn't US "Common Rule" holds that best practice for consent revocation is to destroy all samples from a person who revoked consent.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Destroying samples isn't quite the same as destroying data, though. I haven't had to deal with revoked consent myself but my understanding is that the usual process is to review the case to assess risks to the participant and study of continuing to use their data, since there are a lot of issues to consider including that omitting the data could cause damage to the study and therefore the other participants. If a participant is no longer affected by the study e.g. not receiving any treatment then it's highly unlikely for the balance to come out in favor of omitting them.

Comment: The only exception I can think of would be a case where anonymity is impossible, which would be pretty unusual for most studies.

Comment: You still haven't indicated whether this has happened or is just a worry that it might. Please add that information.

Answer (score 4):

There's perhaps a disconnect in expectations here - you say 'agreement' to do research, which implies you're thinking of the discussion with the IRB as a contract or similar. However, IRB reviews are generally framed in terms of approval - that is, they say that based on current information, you may conduct the research you describe. Because this is a unilateral decision by the IRB, it can also terminate these approvals for any given study at any time. Most commonly this is because the researcher is not following the agreed plans or other new information comes to light which affects the approval, but there are probably numerous other reasons.

Typically, they have to be able to justify this decision, but nothing you mention in your post would seem to prevent them from terminating an approval (even primary data gathering being completed).

As others mention in the comments, you will probably get better answers by providing more detail, but the general answer to your headline question at the moment is 'yes'.

Comment: Yes. I think that "Most commonly this is because the researcher is not following the agreed plans" is the key here.

Comment: To support your answer, drug trials are often halted part way through based upon preliminary results. Here is an example from a recent news https://www.reuters.com/business/healthcare-pharmaceuticals/bayer-cancels-asundexian-phase-iii-study-program-2023-11-20/.

Comment: See my comment on the OP and compare to the original question. I think edits have messed up OP's intended question. The agreement for research is likely a consent process with e.g. a school for children, not an IRB approval with a higher ed institution. They would first get IRB approval, and then seek agreements with their study sites to do research there with the students or teachers.

Comment: @BryanKrause That's a good point - looking back at the original version of the question it's unclear if an IRB approval was meant at all. I think in almost all cases the answer of if an ethical approval for research can be terminated will still be 'yes', but the details will definitely depend a lot on what exactly is being asked.

Comment: @BryanKrause, it was the OP that added the IRB in the text. I added the tag and changed the title. But it was the OP that indicates IRB approval. And, like you, I'd have preferred more information, which is why I haven't tried to answer.

Comment: @Buffy I don't think the text OP added indicated that they were asking about losing IRB approval. They were saying they have IRB approval and then asking if a participating facility can revoke their consent.

Comment: @StephenMcMahon I think OP is worried about data they've already collected, and if they can lose access to their collected data if a study site says they don't want to participate anymore. I could see this concern especially if, for example, the study concludes something that the school doesn't want concluded (even if they are not named; I'm aware of cases where it's happened, especially when the research topic is something like racial disparities in education). Unfortunately they did not clarify these concerns before the question was reopened and answered.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, at least in the US.  There are legal requirements for re-reviews after a certain amount of years.  The study approval will lapse if you don't keep up on the paperwork.

If you expect to re-contact participants years after they sign a consent, you need to work to keep the study open.

Also, there are reporting requirements to the IRB (and sometimes the funding institutes) for certain types of events during a study.  Some of these types of events may force the IRB's hand, calling for a change in protocol, or even a suspension of approval.

If the question involves a the institution that owns the research site and a separate IRB, the mechanism may be a bit different, but yes, the approval can be withdrawn.  The site can simply mandate what can go on at the site.  If the site is shut down for purposes of the investigator's research, then that would be reported to the IRB, which will probably yank approval (because there is no site for the research) unless acceptable substitution can be made.